# Microsoft Comfort Optical Mouse 3000 back-button

Tags: 16.04, mouse

Is there a process / command that can configure the back-button of MS mouse?  The other controls of the mouse function properly.

I tried this process but was not successful

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1629594

> xinput set-button-map "Microsoft Microsoft Optical Mouse with Tilt
>   Wheel" 1 2 3 4 5 6 9 7 8

unable to find device 'Microsoft Microsoft Optical Mouse with Tilt Wheel'

## UPDATE:

This command requires that the mouse be plugged in via USB and not PS2 adapter.  The functionality works, however, if the mouse is unpluged and plugged in again the command has to be issued again.

Any suggestions to make the setting "stick", would be appreciated.

> xinput --list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Optical Mouse with Tilt Wheel id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam [2 MP Macro]                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

[image]